# MPAndroidChart display less number of x-axis against the plotted values

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am working with MPAndroidChart to show a line graph with date values.

I am getting less number of x-axis values against the plotted values.

And I am using Kotlin language.

My code snippets are below.

```
private fun loadGraphData() {
        val list1 = ArrayList<ComponentModel>()            

        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-11T09:47:00+00:00", 99.0f))
        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-12T09:47:00+00:00", 100.0f))
        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-13T09:47:00+00:00", 101.0f))
        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-14T09:47:00+00:00", 102.0f))

        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-15T09:47:00+00:00", 99.0f))
        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-16T09:47:00+00:00", 100.0f))
        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-17T09:47:00+00:00", 101.0f))
        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-18T09:47:00+00:00", 102.0f))

        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-19T09:47:00+00:00", 99.0f))
        list1.add(ComponentModel("2010-12-20T09:47:00+00:00", 100.0f))

        val entries = populateDataInGraph(list1)
        val dataSet = LineDataSet(entries, "Test Result")
        dataSet.apply {
            color = Color.RED
            setDrawValues(false)
            setDrawCircleHole(false)
            setCircleColor(Color.RED)
        }
        img_test_result_graph.apply {

            xAxis.apply {
                xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
                setDrawGridLines(false)
                textSize = 4f
                valueFormatter = DateValueFormatter()
                isGranularityEnabled = true
                granularity = 1f
                labelCount = list1.size
            }
            axisLeft.apply {
                setDrawGridLines(false)
                valueFormatter = YAxisDataFormatter()
                granularity = 1f
                addLimitLine(LimitLine(100.0f, "Normal").also { it.lineColor = Color.GREEN })
            }
            axisRight.isEnabled = false
            data = LineData(dataSet)
            setScaleEnabled(true)
            description.text = ""
            invalidate()
        }

    }
```

I tried with granularity from the issues posted in github too.
Even I getting the graph as below 
[image]

Help on this to show x-axis values equals to plotted values.

Comment: Have you check Interaction with the Chart. It happens when you plotted more numbers of x-axis values to adjust for a filling MPAndroidChart, Please visit this Document https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart

Comment: @Dhananjay Will have look at the link. Thank you :)

Comment: I have enabled only x axis scaling. Seems somewhat good. Thanks for responding . Will check more and have healthy sharing on this.